# Asp.Net 4: How to route to a web form in an MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704338/asp-net-4-0-web-forms-routing-default-wildcard-route/2704567#2704567) by Nick Craver implements routing to web forms like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("defaultRoute", "{*value}", "~/Missing.aspx");
```

However we get an error of `Route data must contain an item named controller`.

**Is it possible to route to a web form?**

We need to "catch" and route within routing rather than not hitting any routes then defaulting to the actual name.  I don't think routing is specific to MVC, although we are routing to a web form that exists within an MVC site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Routing was introduced with ASP.NET MVC its actually a separate mechanism.  For your issue, are you entirely sure you are using `MapPageRoute` instead of `MapRoute`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you will need to add an IgnoreRoute in your RegisterRoutes method.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
```

This will tell MVC to not try to route this like it would normally.  This is for .Net 4.0.

[Here is some more details on this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc).

### EDIT - SINCE MY INITIAL ABOVE ANSWER....

[Scott Hanselman just created a nice post on integrating the two environments](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ScottHanselman+%28Scott+Hanselman+-+ComputerZen.com%29).  Have a look at it.  I imagine it is something in the initial setup of everything that may have been missed or not configured correctly that will be the culprit.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?  Would be nice to know if someone would explain why they thought my answer was "bad".... :-)

Comment: My guess is something to do with the `IgnoreRoute` as I don't think that's the 'preferred' way, but if your method was used you'd likely also need to use `RouteExistingFiles = true` as the default is false.

Comment: @Dan - Nice comment on RouteExistingFiles = true.  I will have to look that up.

Comment: We should have a rally or nice turn around badge.... Going from -1 to +2. Sweet! :-) Glad my edit helps @dr-zim! :-)